# Having css issue

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/JDwjJ/

Please take a look at this code

The problems are followings:

- #nav must be at the top of #main, not side by side;
- How can I center #nav inside #container if I don't exact to set exact width for it? Tried margin: 0 auto; no success?

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` will only work if the #nav element has a specified width.

Comment: @TiesonT.  width of nav is unknown. website is multilanguage, so width changes. How can I center nav without defining exact width or is there any other way for variable width?

Comment: Without digging into your specific ruleset, I can't say, but it's a hard and fast rule that a browser cannot actually apply an "auto" margin unless the dimensions of the element are known. All "auto" really does is say "split what's left evenly on both sides."

Answer (score 2):

Remove unnecessary `float` form your `#nav` & `ul`. Then define `width` to your `#nav` for example `600px`

```
#nav{
 width:600px;
}
#nav ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/JDwjJ/1/

**UPDATED**
If the width is unknown then you can use `display:inline-block` property for this:

```
    #nav {
        display:inline-block;
        *display:inline/* For IE7*/
        *zoom:1/* For IE7*/
    }
    #container{
        text-align:center;
    }  
   #main{
        text-align:left;
   }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/JDwjJ/8/

Comment: I already told that, width of nav is unknown. website is multilanguage, so width changes. How can I center nav without defining exact width or is there any other way for variable width?

Answer (score 2):

For the

1.nav must be at the top of #main, not side by side;

just apply

```
clear:both
```

on the main div

2.How can I center #nav inside #container if I don't exact to set exact width for it? Tried margin: 0 auto; no success?

you have to set certain width for this content container by this margin 0 auto will work

**update** : please take a look if you need the same

http://jsfiddle.net/JDwjJ/9/

Comment: width of nav is unknown. website is multilanguage, so width changes. How can I center nav without defining exact width or is there any other way for variable width?

Comment: @epic_syntax define widht as 100% that wont hurt you in any case, check my updated answer if it's what you need :)

Comment: lol.. that will force resive navigation bar to fit parent div width, even if text of navigation menu is not that long

Comment: so I am out now no more guesses :D